# Makefile for C code

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cplex

I inherited a code which has a makefile, but so far I was unable to run it on a linux server. The main complain of the compiler is that it is unable to load `libgmp.so.3` : `error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3`. I know that `libgmp.so.10` exists on this server, but I was wondering which part of the makefile needs to be changed so the compiler looks for `libgmp.so.10` rather than `libgmp.so.3`.

```bash
OPTFLAG         = -O2 -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG 
LDFLAGS     = -O2 -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -DNDEBUG -lm -pthread

COMPILER        = gcc ${OPTFLAG}
LINKER          = gcc ${LDFLAGS}

# CPLEX directory 
CPLEX_HOME     = /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex
CPLEX_INC      = ${CPLEX_HOME}/include/
CPLEX_LIB      = ${CPLEX_HOME}/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/ -lcplex

# Compile the main file
code: code.c
    ${COMPILER} -c code.c -o code.o -I${CPLEX_INC}
    ${LINKER} -o code code.o -L${CPLEX_LIB}     

clean::
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f ${LIB}/*.o
    rm -f *~
    rm -f ${SRC}/*~ ${INCLUDE}/*~
```

Comment: You may need to add the directory that contains the library to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable - `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/parent/dir/of/library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Can you run `ldd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/*cplex*` and post the output?

Comment: @kichik `>ldd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static‌​_pic/*cplex*
ldd: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static‌​_pic/*cplex*: No such file or directory`

Comment: For CPLEX 12.7.1 (currently the latest version) and the C Callable Library (a static library), you need to link with `-lm -pthread` (`libgmp` is not a dependency). The issue you're having with `libgmp` is **not** CPLEX related.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild whatever program or library uses `libgmp.so.3` from source code.  Could you provide the exact command run by `make` and the error message it produces?

**EDIT** The problem here is that the system has installed a version of the IBM CPLEX software which comes with its own GCC binary, and that GCC binary uses `libgmp.so.3`.  The easiest way to fix this would be to upgrade the CPLEX software to a version which supports the operating system being used, or use the software on the operating system for which it was written (i.e., something really old that actually ships `libgmp.so.3`).

Comment: This is the error message: `gcc -O2 -Wall -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG  -c code.c -o code.o -I/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include/
/opt/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that `gcc` is not the system compiler, but something from `/opt/local/bin`? Have you changed the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: All I have changed was `llvm-gcc` to `gcc` and the address to cplex.

Comment: The question is why the `gcc` command tries to run the C compiler from the directory `/opt/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0‌`. Probably you should try `/usr/bin/gcc` instead of `gcc`. Alternatively, upgrade to a newer version of IBM CPLEX which matches your operating system.

Comment: Changing `gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc` changed the error message to `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @Iman, how did you changed `llvm-gcc` to `gcc`?  Did you deinstall `gcc` first? are both compilers running on your system?  Why do you have binaries requesting two different versions of the same library running on the same system.  Are you getting packages from two different distributions? (this is common in debian/ubuntu users, and leads to these kind of problems)

Comment: @LuisColorado As I mentioned in my original question, I received this code from someone else. They had specified `llvm-gcc` as compiler in their Makefile. Since `llvm-gcc` is not available on the server I am using, I simply replaced it by `gcc` in the Makefile.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, I'm trying to understand your EDIT. This code as well as its Makefile are old, while the version of CPLEX installed on the server is the newest. I use CPLEX with my C++ code with no problem, but this code is in C and uses many callables from CPLEX which are only defined in C, so I cannot transform it to C++.

Comment: @Iman, I'm afraid you have done more than _changing the compiler name in the `Makefile`_.  The lack of a shared object version is a consequence of doing nasty things in the system (things like partially installing a program, without providing or solving all its dependencies, ignoring the warnings given by the package management system or worse, having several system repositories, based on different versions of the system ---in this case, a dependency to version 3 of `libgmp.so`)

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way it to install `libgmp-dev` package, from your linux distribution. GMP is a package library to do multiple precision calculations on large integers, which is probably needed by your program.  As you put in some comments, adding `-L/usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10` is an error, as `-L` option allows to add a **directory** to search for libraries, and not a specific library.

If only the library is needed and no header file is missing in your compilation (this is something strange, but sometimes happen) then you can still link with only the `libgmp.so.10` object, but you have to do in a something nasty way.  Just add `/usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10` as an object file (not a library, with `-l` option) to your link command.

## EDIT

From looking more closely your `Makefile` I see no reference to the `libgmp.so.3` library, so I only can assume this is a indirect reference from some other already compiled library that comes from outside with your package.  Just use

```
ldd lib<nameOfLibrary>.so.x.x
```

with all the libraries needed by your final executable, so see which shared objetc is the one that requests `libgmp.so.3` soname, and then recompile it, reinstall it, or use your system's libraries  **ONLY**, and not mesh anymore with libraries coming from another system.  For example you can try (this is an expensive command, but it will get the answer)

```
find / -name "lib*.so.*" -print | xargs ldd > all_libs.lddout
```

and then find `all_libs.lddout` to see which library uses `libgmp.so.3` (this will be the outdated library)  You'll need to deinstall it or upgrade it, to be able to continue.

Linux systems have a library version system that allows an executable to be able to load different versions of the same library and allow them to live together in the same system.  One of two: or you are able to locate the sources of version 3 of the shared `libgmp.so.3` library and install it on your system, or you'll need to update the libraries your program uses to be able to link with the `libgmp.so.10` already installed on your system.

## 2ND EDIT

As I see in the comments, you have changed the default compiler on your system by another coming possibly from other linux distribution (as your installed library is `libgmp.so.10` while the one `cc1` requests is `libgmp.so.3`, which is not installed on your system.

Installing a different compiler from the one you have installed, and doing that without previously deinstalling the other compiler, can lead you to this kind of problems.

The most reliable thing you can do is to reinstall the compiler from your distribution, or better, reinstall the whole linux system, as you have probably broken many things that will be emerging as you use your system.  There's very poor info on what you have done to go further in your problem.  Anyway, my recommendation is to not use the comment parts to add new information about your problem, just edit your question and add all those new information to it.

Comment: The distribution version of GMP is to new for a build tool, so that it fails to run. A `-dev` package is not going to fix that. You need a compatible operating system version, or perhaps a compat package.

Comment: The error says `error while loading shared libraries` and this is a runtime error... The PO has not linked with the system library, so the runtime and the library required mismatch.  But as we have an executable at all, I have to assume the linking has succeeded.  We only need to install the library in the proper place or use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to specify where to load it from.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, you are right in your assertion, and I had quickly read the question and issued an answer.  I've edited my answer to cope with the runtime error got from the system loader and giving some recommendations to follow.  I expect this will be the right way to go this time.  My apologies for directing the PO in the wrong direction.

Comment: the key error message is in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174587/makefile-for-c-code/45184218?noredirect=1#comment77317832_45174640). They use a special, non-system GCC compiler which cannot run due to the missing library.

Comment: Can I assume at least that ELF binaries are used and/or `binutils` to be able to `ldd(1)` something?  How do you know such things if you see the same information as I?  The problem anyway is a version mismatch in a shared object, and the PO has access to the program `Makefile`, so he has tried to build an executable or we are dealing with precompiled binaries?  Read my edition as it is now, please.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, are you downvoting all the answers to make yours to go upper in the list?  Should we all downvote yours to see where does it go?  Please, don't play downvoting just by downvoting.

Comment: your initial proposal to add an `-L` flag did not help in this situation.

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks for the detailed answer, even though I might not be able to understand it all. First, I am using a server which means I almost have zero permission to make significant changes such as reinstalling or updating a package. I did not change the default compiler of the system. I simply replaced `llvm-gcc` in the makefile to `gcc`, as `gcc` is the only compiler available on this server. I don't believe the problem is coming from anywhere outside of the Makefile as I was able to build and run the same code on XCode which basically doesn't need the user to create a makefile.

Comment: @Iman, sorry for my initial assumptions about your environment.  First, use a new system (or one on which you have complete control) to build your software.  Then test it there, and finaly, put it on the final server it is going to run.  This way you'll have whole control on what you do.  The final conclussion is that your build system is broken (probably the gcc compiler has been incorrectly upgraded to the clang compiler)  You need to put your error in knowledge of your system admin on the server, but I cannot help you more than I've said yet.  Sorry.